# How to make the slide smoother without affecting the size of the element

Tags: jquery

I had an issue regarding the slide effect.

Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3me0cvsa/9/

I've noticed that during the slide transition, the size of the element reduced. How can I prevent this kind of issue? A smooth slide without something that isn't look right. The jquery is working. Just the result when sliding. Is it because of hide()?

```js
$("#btn").click(function() {
   $('.box:visible').eq(0).hide('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 1000);
 });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px dotted red;
}

.inner-container {
  width: 1250px;
}

.inner-container:after {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  content: "";
}

.box {
    float: left;
    background: green;
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    opacity: 0.4;
    padding: 104px;
    font-size: 36px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inner-container">
    <div class="box box1">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="box box2">
      2
    </div>
    <div class="box box3">
      3
    </div>
    <div class="box box4">
      4
    </div>
    <div class="box box5">
      5
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<button id="btn">Next Slide</button>
```

Comment: What?? If you are sliding an element, the only way is reducing its size till reach the zero width and / or height. If you don't need the animation, just make `$(element).hide()` with no parameters.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I've set the width and height on the css already but during the transition, it goes small then slide left. Didn't put any css3 transition in my jsfiddle. I need to have the parameter so I will look smooth.